# What is the difference between "they are not arrived yet" and "they have not arrived"?

Tags: tenses

What's the difference between "they are not arrived yet" and "they have not arrived"? Which one is correct?

Comment: "they are not arrived yet" is an anachronistic form.

Comment: But the idiomatic anachronistic form would put *yet* earlier: "They are not yet arrived". Current usage would put *yet* at the end: "They haven't arrived yet."

Answer (score -1):

[yet](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/yet)

> still; until the present time:

To say that something hasn't happened *yet* is to imply that it will happen.  To omit it implies that it's not certain whether it will.

Comment: I don't think that's what the questioner was asking.